# error en promesa

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy comenzando y tengo un código que debo ejecurtarlo solo con promesas por problemas en las versiones de node.

El código dada una lista debe ejecutar un `find` de una colección y según una *criteria* hacer un `resolve` de esta pero no logro hacerlo funcionar y honestamente no sé dónde está el problema. Creo que es en la estructura del código (capa 8).

Acá el código:

```
const comparaPago = (lista) => {
    criterio = {
        "user_id": lista.user,
        "fecha_pago": {
            "$lt": lista.createdAt
        }
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var usuariosTodos = Pagos.find(criterio, function (usuarios) {
            if (usuarios == null) {
                return reject("Error al listar");
            }
            resolve(usuarios);
        }); // fin método callback
    });// fin Promesa
//return lista
}
```

Aquí llamo a la función luego de ejecutar `ListarUsuariosMaxDate` que trae los datos perfectamente. El problema está en la función `comparaPago`, siempre me trae "error al lista"

```
ListarUsuariosMaxDate
    .then(response => {
        var miLista = Promise.all(
            response.map(elemento => {
                return comparaPago(elemento);
            })
        );

        miLista
        .then(lista => {
            return res.status(200).json(lista)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }).then(data2 => {

    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
```

le di un console.log de lista.user y me devuelve algunos id , Gracias y disculpen los errores. Estoy comenzando.

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: error al listar

Comment: Están anidando promesas y no tienes un scope claro de las variables al mezclar arrow functions con normal functions

Comment: gracias por dedicarte un momento a escribir, pero estoy comenzando y no me sirvió de mucho tu comentario pero gracias igual...@Jorius

Comment: Si realmente se está rechazando la `Promise` es porque lo que te devuelve la función `find`, los `usuarios` es `null`. Quizás sea más bien un error en *mongoose*. ¿Has probado de *debugar* por dentro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola elimine los corchetes principales y coloque el criterio dentro del find y me funciono, al parecer es el tipo de ecs, aca el codigo por si acaso alguien le sirve:

```
var comparaPago = (lista) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var listaPagos = Pagos.find({
            "user_id": lista.user,
            "fecha_pago": {
                "$lt": lista.createdAt
            }
        }, (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
            if (!err) {

                return registrosEncontrados

            }
        }
        ).sort({ fecha_pago: -1 })
            .limit(1)
        resolve(listaPagos);

    });
```

no se la razon...

Comment: Sigo preguntándome ¿porqué usas `var` en vez de `let` y `const`? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el callback a la funcion del modelo recibe como primer argumento si ha ocurrido un error o no. Parece que no te esta dando error y por eso el valor de `usuarios` es "null"

Modifica el codigo de la siguiente forma:

```
const comparaPago = (lista) => {
    criterio = {
        "user_id": lista.user,
        "fecha_pago": {
            "$lt": lista.createdAt
        }
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var usuariosTodos = Pagos.find(criterio, function (err, usuarios) {
            if (err || usuarios == null) {
                return reject("Error al listar");
            }
            resolve(usuarios);
        }); // fin método callback
    });// fin Promesa
//return lista
}
```

Comment: Me devuelve todos los valores null y no deberia, incluso si hago un find sin criterios lo devuelve una serie de valores null, no se si sera el llamado de la funcion???

Comment: haz probado a poner un `console.log(err, usuarios);` antes del if a ver que valor tiene err y usuarios? que valor tiene cada una?